# Executing a C program with a subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to call the following command from a Python script:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.avi -acodec copy -vcodec copy outfile.mp4
```

This was my attempt:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ffmpeg","-i infile.avi", "-acodec copy", "-vcodec copy", "outfile.mp4")
```

I also tried

```
call(["ffmpeg","-i infile.avi -acodec copy -vcodec copy outfile.mp4")
```

I received the following error

```
Unrecognized option 'i infile.avi'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

None of these worked, what am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to quote your paramters separately:

```
call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "infile.avi", "-acodec", "copy", "-vcodec", "copy", "outfile.mp4")
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it was my first time using a subprocess. :P

Comment: You can think of it this way - the quoted items in the subprocess list are like quoted items on the command line. For instance, `"echo" "foo"` will work (and print out `foo`), but `"echo foo"` would not (and similarly, `["echo foo"]` wouldn't work for subprocess).